# What is the hyphen for, apart from trimming whitespace?

Tags: twig

I understand using

```
{{-          remove leading spaces -}}
```

for trimming whitespace, but in the example below, and that I've seen loads, what is the point?

```
{%- if true -%}
```

or

```
{%- endfor %}
```

What purpose does it serve in a control statement? I can find nothing in the documentation about this specifically, but if there is something, please, point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It applies to the full block,

```html
{% for i in 1..10 %}
        {{ i }}
        
{% endfor %}

{%- for i in 1..10 -%}
        {{ i }}
        
{%- endfor -%}
```

*output*

```
    1

    2

    3

    4

    5

    6

    7

    8

    9

    10

12345678910
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/0ygava)

Comment: Many thanks... especially for the demo - Twigfiddle will be immensely helpful to me!